# Form field value from another form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an MS Access form called service that should contain a button (Open) that opens form payment.

The payment form contains a service id field which should be set automatically from the record form service where I pressed open.

How can I make it in Access?

Comment: Just read required value from other form. http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That could be:

```
Dim FormName As String
Dim ServiceId As Long

FormName = "Payment"
ServiceId = Me!ServiceId.Value  ' get value of ServiceId to pass from current form.
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName
Forms(FormName)!ServiceId.Value = ServiceId
```